# Program does nothing when run?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, search, runtime

I wrote this program and have all the code that it should need. At first I was having some run-time errors, but I easily fixed those. Now it shows no visible errors, and when I run it, it does nothing.

In essence, what it should be doing is printing out a list of classes with students and id numbers, which have been merged from two files. It matches the ids of students to the ids of classes and forms them into a list. This all seems to be happening, it just isn't printing it out.

My code is below. Please let me know what you think. I have included a description at the top and markers of where I think the issue starts and ends. Also after the code there is an example of the contents of the two files.

```
/* This program reads in two files, one which contains a list of student names and id numbers,     and another which lists class id numbers.
 * Then, the data is taken into arrays which are then used in different sorts. One sorts the id numbers numerically, one sorts the students
 * alphabetically, and one sorts the class names alphabetically.The id numbers of students are matched to class and both are compiled into
 * a list which then prints out first the class name, then the list of students within it. All done alphabetically.
 * 
 */

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MergingFiles {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
    String[][] studentArray = new String [1000][2];
    String[][] classArray = new String[4000][2];
    int count = 0;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("students.txt"));
    while(sc.hasNextLine()){
     String studentInput = sc.nextLine();
     String name = studentInput.substring(0, 30).trim();
     String id = studentInput.substring(30).trim();
     studentArray[count][0] = name;
     studentArray[count][1] = id;
     count++;
    }
     for(int i = 0; i < count-1; i++){ //sorts id number numerically
      for(int j = 0; j < count-1-i; j++){
        if(studentArray[j][1].compareTo(studentArray[j+1][1]) > 0){
         String holder = studentArray[j][1];
          studentArray[j][1] = studentArray[j+1][1]; 
          studentArray[j+1][1] = holder; 
        }
      }
     }
     int counter3 = 0;
     Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(new File("classes.txt"));
     while(sc2.hasNextLine()){
       int counter2 = 0;
       String classInput = sc2.nextLine(); 
       while(classInput.charAt(counter2)!= ' '){
         counter2++;
       }
       String className = classInput.substring(0, counter2);
       while(classInput.charAt(counter2) == ' '){
         counter2++;
       }
       String idNum = classInput.substring(counter2);


       int low = 0;
       int high = count - 1;
       int mid = (high - low)/2 + low;

       while(!idNum.equals(studentArray[mid][1])){ //binary search
         if(idNum.compareTo(studentArray[mid][1]) < 0){
           high = mid - 1; 
         }else
           low = mid + 1;
         mid = (high - low)/2 + low;
       }

       String studentName2 = studentArray[mid][1];
       classArray[counter3][0] = className;
       classArray[counter2][1] = studentName2;
     }
 //I THINK THE ISSUE STARTS HERE
     for(int a = 0; a < (counter3 - 1); a++){ //sort class names alphabetically
       for(int b = 0; b < counter3-1-a; b++){
         if(classArray[b][0].compareTo(classArray[b+1][0]) > 0){
           String holder2 = classArray[b][0];
           classArray[b][0] = classArray[b+1][0]; 
           classArray[b+1][0] = holder2; 
         }
       }
     }
     for(int c = 0; c < (counter3 - 1); c++){ //sort class names alphabetically
       for(int d = 0; d < counter3-1-c; d++){
         if((classArray[d][0].compareTo(classArray[d+1][0])) == 0){
           if(classArray[d][1].compareTo(classArray[d+1][1]) > 0){
             String holder3 = classArray[d][1];
             classArray[d][1] = classArray[d+1][1]; 
             classArray[d+1][1] = holder3; 
           }
         }
       }
     }
     String currentClass = "";
     for(int s = 0; s < counter3; s++){
       if(!classArray[s][0].equals(currentClass)){
         currentClass = classArray[s][0];
         System.out.print(currentClass);
       }
       System.out.print(classArray[s][1]);
     }
 //THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUE ENDS 
  }                         
}
```

studentArray contents example (without //'s):

```
//Lambert, Desmond              451825335
//Johnston, Michaela            143547061
//Wells, Shirley                942366473
// Blevins, Dawson               407183976
// Roy, Benjamin                 575069268
// Mitchell, Jaquan              285633099
// Freeman, Nayeli               312234364
// Benson, Myles                 755491358
// Wilkinson, Stephany           384506082
// Bradshaw, Nikki               159900631
// Davila, Sarah                 788743448
// Wyatt, Eddie                  253830483
// Ortega, Josh                  891761169
// Pruitt, Deven                 533987743
// Harrison, Aliyah              710258372
// Perez, Emerson                611325979
// Stanton, Sonny                430095944
// Rice, Bruce                   301915859
// Callahan, Brandon             327995163
// Torres, Jovan                 629852538
// Mathis, Timothy               936191071
// Calhoun, Nathanael            107519769
// Mullen, Malik                 711847273
// Sims, Marvin                  519717164
// Pham, Siena                   530779316
// Vincent, Demetrius            618276821
```

etc.

classArray contents example (without //'s):

```
 //ECON101 938597595
 //BUS100 951008337
 //ECON408 620903271
 //PHY101 695451867
 //COSC150 392023624
 //MATH215 557048539
 //COSC325 495522117
 //BUS215 185642398
 //ECON408 807662685
 //MATH215 920062540
 //MATH325 517786537
 //PHY150 915173832
 //BUS100 518392974
 //BUS408 410797598
 //BUS215 152414047
 //PHY150 561839967
```

etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Show the content of `students.txt`.

Comment: It's an extremely long list.

Comment: A representative sample, then. Same goes for your code, if you can: Trim it down to the smallest amount of code that doesn't do what you expect. This is a lot of code to ask people to slog through.

Comment: I have edited in your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add tokens in the txt file and using StringTokenizer have the columns captured per row in the arrays. Once you have all the data in the array, then you should be process the data to merge. 
  When you are saying "The id numbers of students are matched to class and both are compiled into a list which then prints out first the class name, then the list of students within it. All done alphabetically."
  Are you intend to match the id in the student file with class file? if so, the above example values does not show it though.

Also if you have the student and classtxt files, share those and I can try running with them.

Answer (score 0):

Basic problem is,`counter3` is never set to anything besides `0`, so the body of your print loop never executes. You probably want to increment counter3 here, and also use it as the index into classArray for both of these assignment statements (I think you're mistakenly using counter2 to set the student name):

```
classArray[counter3][0] = className;
classArray[counter2][1] = studentName2;
counter3++;
```

By the way, your sorting is broken because you're sorting the student ids without also sorting their names - make sure to shuffle the whole Student[] (`studentArray[i]`) forward instead of only `studentArray[i][1]`. Here's a working example using `Arrays.sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)`:

```
// sort students by id number and sort null elements to end of array
Arrays.sort(studentArray, new Comparator<String[]>() {
    public int compare(String[] student1, String[] student2)
    {
        if (student1[1] == null) return 1;
        if (student2[1] == null) return -1;
        return student1[1].compareTo(student2[1]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Your first suggestion yields a NullPointerException at line 75 which is:
   
    if(classArray[b][0].compareTo(classArray[b+1][0]) > 0){

Also, this way of sorting is required for the project.

Comment: I changed the comparison to account for null elements in the array. The point is, you're moving around the student ids without moving their names, so you're essentially randomizing the students' ids.

Comment: Still, the basic problem is the lack of incrementing counter3.

Comment: I'm incrementing at the place you suggested, and that seems to get rid of the NullPointerException at line 75, but it is replaced by a NullPointerException at line 85, which is doing essentially the same thing as 75, with different variables. I also added a "checkpoint" to see if this loop was now running, and it was, however the other is not. Is there another place I should be incrementing?

Comment: By the way, I have a working version of the code in case you have any other questions.